# is it possible to call a MobxStateTree action from a child model?

Tags: reactjs, mobx-state-tree, mobx-react-lite

I create a Mobx State Tree global state composed by a `DataModel` that contains a `TranslationsDataModel`. In `DataModel` I created a `fetchDataset` function that I would like to call in `TranslationsDataModel` but I get an error saying that `fetchDataset` is not a function and I don't understand why.

This is my code:

`index.ts`:

```js
export const StateModel = types.model('StateModel', {
  data: types.optional(DataModel, {} as DataModelInstance),
})

export const stateInstance = StateModel.create()
export interface StateInstance extends Instance<typeof StateModel> {}
const RootStateContext = createContext<StateInstance | null>(null)
export const Provider = RootStateContext.Provider

export function useMst() {
  const state = useContext(RootStateContext)
  if (state === null) {
    throw new Error('')
  }
  return state
}
```

`DataModel.ts`:

```js
export const DataModel = types
  .model('DataModel', {
    translations: types.optional(TranslationsDataModel, {} as TranslationsDataModelInstance),
  })
  .views((self) => ({
    get root() {
      return getRoot(self)
    },
  }))
  .actions((self) => ({
    fetchDataset: flow(function* fetchDataset<T>(dataUrl: string) {
      try {
        const dataset: T[] = yield fetchCsvDataset<T>(dataUrl)
        return dataset
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`! Error: ${error}`)
        return []
      }
    }),
  }))

export interface DataModelInstance extends Instance<typeof DataModel> {}
```

`TranslationsDataModel.ts`:

```js
const TranslationDatum = types.model('TranslationDatum', {
  key: types.string,
  text: types.string,
})

export const TranslationsDataModel = types
  .model('TranslationsDataModel', {
    translationsDataset: types.optional(t.array(TranslationDatum), []),
  })
  .views((self) => ({
    get root(): DataModelInstance {
      return getRoot(self)
    },
  }))
  .views((self) => ({
    getTranslation(key: string) {
      return '...'
    }
  }))
  .actions((self) => ({
    updateTranslationsDataset(dataset: Translation[]) {
      self.translationsDataset.replace(dataset)
    },
  }))
  .actions((self) => ({
    async afterCreate() {
      const translationsDataset = await self.root.fetchDataset<Translation>('translations.csv')
      self.updateTranslationsDataset(translationsDataset)
    },
  }))

export interface TranslationsDataModelInstance extends Instance<typeof TranslationsDataModel> {}
```

I used the stores in that way:

```js
const Homepage = observer(() => {
  const {
    data: {
      translations: { getTranslation },
    },
  } = useMst()

  return (
    <div>{getTranslation('title')}</div>
  )
})
```

at line `const translationsDataset = await self.root.fetchDataset<Translation>('translations.csv')` I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: self.root.fetchDataset is not a function`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your example `fetchDataset` function is defined in the `DataModel`, and you're trying to call it using `self.root.fetchDataset` from `TranslationsDataModel`, however, the `fetchDataset` function is not directly accessible through `self.root` and this should be the reason why the error occured

### solution:

you should define an action in `TranslationsDataModel` that calls the `fetchDataset` function from the `DataModel`:

```js
export const TranslationsDataModel = types
  .model('TranslationsDataModel', {
    translationsDataset: types.optional(t.array(TranslationDatum), []),
  })
  .views((self) => ({
    get root(): DataModelInstance {
      return getRoot(self)
    },
  }))
  .views((self) => ({
    getTranslation(key: string) {
      return '...'
    }
  }))
  .actions((self) => ({
    updateTranslationsDataset(dataset: Translation[]) {
      self.translationsDataset.replace(dataset)
    },
    async fetchTranslationsDataset() {
      const translationsDataset = await self.root.fetchDataset<Translation>('translations.csv')
      self.updateTranslationsDataset(translationsDataset)
    },
  }))
  .actions((self) => ({
    async afterCreate() {
      await self.fetchTranslationsDataset();
    },
  }));

export interface TranslationsDataModelInstance extends Instance<typeof TranslationsDataModel> {}
```

You can now call `self.fetchTranslationsDataset()` within the `afterCreate` action to initiate the data fetching process using the function from the parent model `DataModel`.

Comment: So there is not another way to have the TranslationDataModel as a child of DataModel (that is a child of the root state) but leaving the fetch function inside the DataModel? ```Root --> DataModel (with fetch())--> TranslationDataModel``` so to have in the future another specific state for another type of data that will be on the same level of ```TranslationDataModel```